# Sorting multiple arrays simultaneously in awk

Tags: sorting, awk, gawk

**Introduction**

Consider the following example `sort.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    a[1]="5"; 
    a[2]="3";
    a[3]="6";

    asort(a)
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++) print a[i]
}
```

Running with `awk -f sort.awk` prints the sorted numbers in array `a` in ascending order:

```
3
5
6
```

**Question**

Consider the extended case of two (and, in general, for `N`) corresponding arrays `a` and `b`

```
a[1]="5"; b[1]="fifth"
a[2]="3"; b[2]="third"
a[3]="6"; b[3]="sixth"
```

and the problem of sorting all arrays "simultaneously".. To achieve this, I need to sort array `a` but also to obtain the indices of the sorting. For this simple case, the indices would be given by

```
ind[1]=2; ind[2]=1; ind[3]=3;
```

Having these indices, I can then print out also the sorted `b` array based on the result of the sorting of array `a`. For instance:

```
for (i=1;i<=3;i++) print a[ind[i]], b[ind[i]]
```

will print the sorted arrays..

See also [Sort associative array with AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342782/sort-associative-array-with-awk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I come up with two methods to do your "simultaneous" sort.

- One is combining the two arrays then sort. This is useful when you just need the output.
- the other one is using gawk's `asorti()`

read codes for details, I think it is easy to understand:

```
BEGIN{
    a[1]="5"; b[1]="fifth"
    a[2]="3"; b[2]="third"
    a[3]="6"; b[3]="sixth"

    #method 1: combine the two arrays before sort
    for(;++i<=3;)
        n[i] = a[i]" "b[i]
    asort(n)
    print "--- method 1: ---"
    for(i=0;++i<=3;)
        print n[i]

    #method 2:
    #here we build a new array/hastable, and use asorti()
    for(i=0;++i<=3;)
        x[a[i]]=b[i]

    asorti(x,t)
    print "--- method 2: ---"
    for(i=0;++i<=3;)
        print t[i],x[t[i]]
}
```

output:

```
kent$  awk -f sort.awk
--- method 1: ---
3 third
5 fifth
6 sixth
--- method 2: ---
3 third
5 fifth
6 sixth
```

**EDIT**

if you want to get the original index, you can try the method3 as following:

```
#method 3: 
print "--- method 3: ---"
for(i=0;++i<=3;)
    c[a[i]] = i;

asort(a)
for(i=0;++i<=3;)
    print a[i], " | related element in b: "b[c[a[i]]], " | original idx: " c[a[i]]
```

the output is:

```
--- method 3: ---
3  | related element in b: third  | original idx: 2
5  | related element in b: fifth  | original idx: 1
6  | related element in b: sixth  | original idx: 3
```

you can see, the original idx is there. if you want to save them into an array, just add `idx[i]=c[a[i]]` in the for loop.

**EDIT2**

method 4: combine with different order, then split to get idx array:

```
#method 4:

for(i=0;++i<=3;)
    m[i] = a[i]"\x99"i 
asort(m)
print "--- method 4: ---"
for(i=0;++i<=3;){
    split(m[i],x,"\x99")
    ind[i]=x[2]
    }

#test ind array:
for(i=0;++i<=3;)
    print i"->"ind[i]
```

output:

```
--- method 4: ---
1->2
2->1
3->3
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks great. Can you also obtain an array `ind` with `ind[1]=2`, `ind[2]=1`, and `ind[3]=3` (as in my question)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on `Kent`s answer, here is a solution that should also obtain the indices:

```
BEGIN {
    a[1]="5";
    a[2]="3";
    a[3]="6";

    for (i=1; i<=3; i++) b[i]=a[i]" "i
    asort(b)
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
      split(b[i],c," ")
      ind[i]=c[2]
    }
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++) print ind[i]
}
```

Comment: ha, didn't see your answer. I just posted almost the same as yours as method4. only different is, I chose the separator `\x99`, which is an invisible char, it would make the solution more generic. (e.g. your array index is string, and has spaces)