Awk: syntax for looping over associative array
I'm trying to parse a file, separated by a comma (CSV file). Imagine a list of books and their authors, the second column is the author. Since the file has millions of rows (around 133M), I cannot do this with Python or Java (I mean, I can, but it takes way too long), so I decided to use bash or zsh (which is the interpreter installed in the Mac).
I need to count how many books each author has, which means, counting the occurrences of each unique value on the second column.
#!/bin/zsh

awk -v FS="," 'NR > 1 {        
  author_id = $2;              
  count[$author_id]++;         
} 
END {                            
  PROCINFO["sorted_in_place"] = 1;  
  for (author_id, count) in count; {
    printf "%d, %d\n", author_id, count;  
  }
}' "~/list_of_books_per_author.csv" | sort -nrk2,2 | head -n 10

I keep getting this error:
awk: syntax error at source line 7
 context is
      for >>>  (author_id, <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 7
awk: illegal statement at source line 7

I'm not really aware of what I'm doing wrong now. How do you iterate an associative array, when you want both values, key and value?

I don't get your question. Your title says a bash/zsh error (which by itself is already odd - an error comes either form bash or from zsh, but not from both,  and there is no bash involved in your code), and then you show an error reported by awk, which even has a different message from what you write in the question's title. Please be a bit more exact when asking a question.

As for the error message, $foo in awk refers to the input field, the number of which is stored in the variable foo. Probably you mean count[author_id].

@user1934428 Well, I have run the script with both and both have returned the same error. I'm not sure if the associative array is even being filled or if it's failing before. But in this case of the error, it seems to be happening in the for, which is after the associative array filling.

Since you didn't even show how you executed your script, we can not know which shell you used. Aside from this, one question should focus ideally on one programming language, and since the error is not produced by the shell anyway, you could equally well run it with POSIX shell as well.

I can not find anything about PROCINFO["sorted_in_place"] in documentation. What is it supposed to do? What version of awk are you using?

I rolled back your latest edit; if you want to post an answer of your own, do that (use the "Post Your Answer" button below) instead of editing the question.

@Daweo it's form gawk(https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html)? but I didn't know it till now. When googling how to sort the associative array, found an answer using it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342782/sort-associative-array-with-awk)

@user3049941 documentation shows that you might affect traversal by setting PROCINFO["sorted_in"] there is not mention of PROCINFO["sorted_in_place"] therefore I must assume it is either non-GNU AWK or user is exploiting non-documented obscure feature of GNU AWK.

I don't see the string "sorted_in_place" present anywhere in that linked Q&A...

To be honest, I don't even know where I got that from (it was copy-paste), but it does work. I just replaced it for sorted_in and produced the same result. awk version: 20200816. gawk version: GNU Awk 5.3.0, API 4.0, (GNU MPFR 4.2.1, GNU MP 6.3.0)

PROCINFO["sorted_in_place"] = 1 isn't some undocumented feature - it's you manually creating a new array cell with an index that sorta looks like the gawk one but doesn't actually do anything. gawk allows you to add superfluous entries to PROCINFO and simply ignores anything not documented. You can even do PROCINFO["sorted_by_FS"] = "" too if you like. gawk wouldn't complain at all, but also nothing happens as a result since sorted_by_FS isnt part of its lingo

@user3049941 : as for actual PROCINFO["sorted_in"] there's a very specific list of values that's meaningful, like "@ind_num_asc" or "@val_str_desc" etc. See gawk's site for full list. But by and large, the ones u likely want would simply be permutations of the 2 examples i listed. ind is for sorting the (ind)ex, and val is for sorting the array cell (val)ue instead.

gawk doesn't allow the user to mess with SYMTAB and FUNCTAB at all, and I'd caution with meddling ARGV unless you know what you're doing (unless you're already in the END { } block, in which case do whatever you want to ARGV). But for ENVIRON and PROCINFO, if you don't need any of the info it provides, it's perfectly safe to clear them both and use them as your own temp arrays instead.

Awk is completely its own language, and completely distinct from both Bash and Zsh (which between themselves are also two distinct, incompatible languages, though related). However, if you are learning to use the shell, you will probably also want to learn at least the basics of Awk (and sed), too.
Your attempt to loop over an associative array uses completely the wrong syntax. You want
  for (author_id in count) {
    printf "%d, %d\n", count[author_id], author_id;  
  }

Note also how there should be no semicolon before the opening brace.
I'm guessing you also meant
  count[author_id]++;

earlier in the script. ($author_id would use the integer in author_id as the index into the fields; so if author_id is 3, you were doing count[$3]++)
Depending on how complex your CSV file is, Awk may or may not be inadequate. It copes well with completely trivial CSV files, but is less ideal for complex ones with quoted literal commas and/or quoted literal newlines in the CSV data.
You are probably doing something wrong if you think Awk is going to be much faster than compiled Java. Python is probably a bit slower, but none of them should be catastrophically slow when it comes to reading one line at a time and spitting out a result. (But if you mean it would take longer for you to write a quick program for this in Java, that's probably true.)
As a further aside, you want ~/"list_of_books_per_author.csv"; at least in Bash, the tilde will not be expanded if it is in double quotes.

You're right. I've been using Linux for some years, now forced to work with Mac, but to be honest, I rarely need to do anything like this (I use the terminal a lot, but rarely do I have to do any kind of script- never needed to).
Your answer helped me fix the script, and it worked.
In this case, the file is 15 GB, few columns (mostly numbers in string format, no scape characger), and over 133M rows. Python took almost 20 minutes. The script took less than 2m. Now I wonder how long would it take for Java to do it.

Without access to your data, it's pretty futile to speculate. If there is a huge number of authors, that will affect memory management, while otherwise the running time will probably be dominated by I/O. I find it hard to imagine that a Python script would be significantly slower than Awk if correctly written; and again, Java, as a compiled language, should be quicker to execute if you are not doing something horribly wrong in the code.

@user3049941 : macs nowadays are actually great - it's a GUI interface comparable to Windows (not the awkward sorta GUI that is Gnome and KDE in Linux), is a full blown BSD 4.4 beneath the surface without any extra layers like Microsoft's approach to Linux, while being powered by a CPU that's making Intel panic scream. The most extreme test I've ever done saw gawk w/ GMP complete a Mersenne prime validation in slightly less than 4 mins while python3 kept going for 45mins - for ONE SINGLE number (and I already used their built in pow( ) with 3 args instead of writing custom func.

I created a file with 133 million unique authors. This Awk script ran in 5.5 minutes whereas the equivalent trivial Python script with csv and collections.Counter took 51.5 minutes to process the same file. So yeah, if you have a lot of unique authors, Python's memory management overhead is going to be significant.

@tripee I just realized that my example of the data is misleading. The actual data is all strings representing numbers. An item_id to call it somehow, and an id to group by and count. The rest of the columns are just numbers that could or could not be there).
item_id,id,col1,col3,col4
555,1,1,1.1,2
666,1,,,
555,2,0.5,1
666,3,3.1,0,1

No more than 9.5k of different id (second column), and each id might have between 100 to 27000 items (item_id).  This is a one time operation, to get the top ten id (with most item).

@RAREKpopManifesto I like the Mac, now that I've been using it for a year, but I had many issues with docker due to the arm64 arch (due to the images being for amd64 running simulated), but they seem to have been solved now.

It doesn't really matter what the other data are, as long as it's not dozens of kilobytes or more per line. I used "foo",1,"bar", "foo",2,"bar" etc for my simple benchmark.

You got an answer to the question you asked about your awk error but in regards to "what I'm doing wrong now", it sounds to me like you're interested in speed of execution and so I wouldn't do all that work in awk and then pipe it to sort, I'd sort first and then pipe it to awk if necessary. Consider this alternative approach:
$ cat file
foo,Clive Barker
bar,Danielle Steele
etc,Clive Barker


$ cut -d, -f2 file | sort | uniq -c
      2 Clive Barker
      1 Danielle Steele

If you want the output rows ordered by count then pipe the above to sort -n or sort -nr as you like:
$ cut -d, -f2 file | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 Danielle Steele
      2 Clive Barker


$ cut -d, -f2 file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
      2 Clive Barker
      1 Danielle Steele

If you want the output columns in a different order, pipe the above to either of these (after piping to sort -n or sort -nr if you like):
$ cut -d, -f2 file | sort | uniq -c |
    sed 's/ *\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)/\2, \1/'
Clive Barker, 2
Danielle Steele, 1


$ cut -d, -f2 file | sort | uniq -c |
    awk -v OFS=', ' '{n=$1; sub(/ +[0-9]+ /,""); print $0, n}'
Clive Barker, 2
Danielle Steele, 1

I doubt if you really want | sort -nrk2,2 from your script, btw, as that'd sort by the author's second name. You probably meant | sort -t, -nrk2,2.

Oh, my manager did something similar to that:
cut -f 2 -d , the_file.csv | tr -c '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10

his numbers differed from mine, but at least at the top, we had the same 4 or 5, in a different order (the only one that kept the order was the one with 27k items)

tr -c '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' has multiple problems and won't do what you need. What I show will do what you need (as I understand it from your question).

I think he tried to ignore the no ANSII characters that exist in the file because it seems to have the Windows encoding, not the UTF-8. But it was just a one-time thing, once I've got the ids I needed with most items/rows, I could totally do the rest with Spark in my machine, once I could filter the huge file by one id or two (the ones with most items).
